# Using a default class literal value on an annotation

Tags: java, generics, annotations

I want to annotate some of the fields of a given bean class with the following annotation:

```
@Target({FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Process {

    Class<? extends ProcessingStrategy> using() default DefaultImplStrategy.class;

}
```

Without going into the domain too much, each annotated property needs to have a ProcessingStrategy defined on it, hence the using() property on the annotation. That's fine and works the way I'd like it to.

I also want to specify a default implementation of the strategy, to be used most of the time (the default defined below). This works fine in Eclipse.

However, when I try to compile this using a regular JDK (invoked through maven) I get the following error:

```
found   : java.lang.Class<DefaultImplStrategy>
required: java.lang.Class<? extends ProcessingStrategy>
```

I'm guessing it's some combination of generics, annotations, class literals and defaulting that are at fault here but I honestly do not know why. I've had a look at the rules around default values in the JLS and I don't seem to be violating anything.

Given that DefaultImplStrategy definitely implements ProcessingStrategy, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the JDK version?

Comment: In IntelliJ with jdk1.5.0_19 it compiles fine.

Comment: Hmm... It works in Eclipse and IntelliJ, and I've just tried something similar (I don't have the original code to hand) using command-line javac and it works fine. I can only assume that the build process is going wrong somewhere. I'll look at it tomorrow and post what I figure out.

Comment: Looks somewhat related to: http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg108865.html

... but still not found the specifics.

Comment: Small update: it looks like Project Lombok is involved. If I remove Lombok from the project entirely, Maven compiles. If I don't, it gives the error above. Shot in the dark here is that the lombok annotation processor is not being picked up correctly using javac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version of this is that some combination of maven, Lombok and default annotations don't play nicely together. The longer version is [on the Lombok mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/project-lombok/browse_thread/thread/d3df372444943efc).

The solution is relatively simple: fully qualify the default Type i.e.

```
@Target({FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Process {

    Class<? extends ProcessingStrategy> using() default com.example.processing.DefaultImplStrategy.class;

}
```

Comment: It's also happening in my ant-based project which doesn't use Lombok, so it must be a problem with the jdk itself

Comment: @Aldo while I don't need this myself now (beyond the workaround I have), I'd love to hear what the issue is if you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but if you give the full class path to DefaultImplStrategy it will probably work

Comment: Umm, yeah. That's exactly what I said in my answer to this (my own) question.